# Use SSH plugin for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I try to use the [SSH Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin) for jenkins. I go to the global configuration of my jenkins where I try to describe my configuration.
This is what I have

```
Hostname: IP of server
Port: 22
Username: usernamex
Keyfile: Here I need to place the key which is necessary to ssh
```

The problem is the key. I'm not able to upload a key? How do I have to do or solve this? To which path is this pointing? So maybe I'm able to put the key in the right path on my server.

Comment: You need to indicate the path where the key is on the machine, eg `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, either you point out the private key file path, or directly copy the content of private key and paste it in the ssh key config page.

Br,

Tim